# How copy Queue to other Queue using static method .Schildt

Tags: java, queue

Whell,in this exercise need:
Create a static method that copies the contents of one type of queue into another. Really, i haven`t no ideas how is make it. Please help me :(

I tried make new class like this, and actually he don`t show nothing and i understand becouse , but i made it that see what a return method get(), and they return --Queue is empty, ok how just i thouth, but how i can return array with char? or something else, ohhh, i dont now :(

```
 public class TestQueue { 
   public static void CQueue(ICharQ a) {

  a.get();
   System.out.println("  " + a);
  }
}
```

Inteface:

```
public interface ICharQ{        
    void put (char ch);  //putting symb to queue
    char get(); 

    void reset ();
    default char reset1(){return '-';}
}
```

Code of Queues:

```
 class FixedQueue implements ICharQ {
private char q[]; // this array holds the queue
private int putloc, getloc; // the put and get indices

// Construct an empty queue given its size.

public FixedQueue(int size) {
    q = new char[size]; // allocate memory for queue

    putloc = getloc = 0;
}

// Put a characer into the queue.

public void put(char ch) {
    if(putloc==q.length) {
        System.out.println(" -- Queue is full.");
        return;
    }

    q[putloc++] = ch;
}

// Get a character from the queue.

public char get() {
    if(getloc == putloc) {

        System.out.println(" -- Queue is empty.");

        return (char) 0;

    }

    return q[getloc++];
}
```

}

// A circular queue.

```
class CircularQueue implements ICharQ {
private char q[]; // this array holds the queue
private int putloc, getloc; // the put and get indices

// Construct an empty queue given its size.

public CircularQueue(int size) {
    q = new char[size+1]; // allocate memory for queue
    putloc = getloc = 0;
}

// Put a characer into the queue.

public void put(char ch) {
/* Queue is full if either putloc is one less than
   getloc, or if putloc is at the end of the array
   and getloc is at the beginning. */

    if(putloc+1==getloc |
            ((putloc==q.length-1) & (getloc==0))) {
        System.out.println(" -- Queue is full.");
        return;
    }

    q[putloc++] = ch;
    if(putloc==q.length) putloc = 0; // loop back

}

// Get a character from the queue.

public char get() {
    if(getloc == putloc) {
        System.out.println(" -- Queue is empty.");
        return (char) 0;
    }

    char ch = q[getloc++];
    if(getloc==q.length) getloc = 0; // loop back
    return ch;
}
public void reset(int res) {
    putloc=getloc=0;
    q = new char[res];
    System.out.println(" ---Queue have not items= ZERO"+q);

}

}
```

// A dynamic queue.

```
class DynQueue implements ICharQ {
private char q[]; // this array holds the queue
private int putloc, getloc; // the put and get indices

// Construct an empty queue given its size.

public DynQueue(int size) {
    q = new char[size]; // allocate memory for queue
    putloc = getloc = 0;
}
// Put a characer into the queue.
public void put(char ch) {
    if(putloc==q.length) {
        // increase queue size
        char t[] = new char[q.length * 2];

        // copy elements into new queue

        for(int i=0; i < q.length; i++)
            t[i] = q[i];

        q = t;
    }

    q[putloc++] = ch;
}

// Get a character from the queue.

public char get() {
    if(getloc == putloc) {
        System.out.println(" -- Queue is empty.");
        return (char) 0;
    }

    return q[getloc++];
}
public void reset(int res) {
    putloc=getloc=0;
    q = new char[res];
    System.out.println(" ---Queue have not items= ZERO"+q[10]);

}
```

}

```
// Demonstrate the ICharQ interface.

    class IQDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    FixedQueue q1 = new FixedQueue(10);
    DynQueue q2 = new DynQueue(10);
    CircularQueue q3 = new CircularQueue(10);

    ICharQ iQ;

    char ch;
    int i;

    iQ = q1;
    // Put some characters into fixed queue.

    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
        iQ.put((char) ('A' + i));

    // Show the queue.

    System.out.print("Contents of fixed queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        ch = iQ.get();
        System.out.print(ch);
    }



    System.out.println();

    iQ = q2;

    // Put some characters into dynamic queue.

    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
        iQ.put((char) ('Z' - i));

    // Show the queue.

    System.out.print("Contents of dynamic queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        ch = iQ.get();
        System.out.print(ch);
    }

    System.out.println();

    iQ = q3;
    // Put some characters into circular queue.

    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
        iQ.put((char) ('A' + i));

    // Show the queue.

    System.out.print("Contents of circular queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        ch = iQ.get();
        System.out.print(ch);
    }

    System.out.println();

    // Put more characters into circular queue.

    for(i=10; i < 20; i++)
        iQ.put((char) ('A' + i));

    // Show the queue.

    System.out.print("Contents of circular queue: ");
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        ch = iQ.get();
        System.out.print(ch);
    }

    System.out.println("\nStore and consume from" +
            " circular queue.");

    // Use and consume from circular queue.

    for(i=0; i < 20; i++) {
        iQ.put((char) ('A' + i));
        ch = iQ.get();
        System.out.print(ch);


  } 
  }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work like this. You dont dump your assignment and *all* the code you have written so far. You tell us exactly where you are stuck, where your code behaves not as expected. It is not our responsibility to digest all of your code, to then figure where you deviate from your assignment.

Comment: uupps, mine mistake, my English not good, and i'm don't understand ,now i underground:) Thanks ;)

Comment: uupps, mine mistake, my English not good, and i'm don't understood ,now i understand:) Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Think of the input and output you expect when copying a Queue. What will you need to create a copy? First you'll need the original Queue, then you'll need to return a copy of the original.

```
public static ICharQ /*copy*/ CQueue(ICharQ original)
```

Now using your interface methods available

```
put (char ch);
char get();
```

You can use the known methods to create a loop that grabs a character from the original Queue `get()` until it's empty and inserts each character into the copy using put `(char ch)`

Now using everything mentioned above to create an algorithm to loop until no characters are left to copy and returning the copy created.

```
public static ICharQ CQueue(ICharQ original)
{
    ICharQ copy = new FixedQueue(); //change this to use an if/else using instance of, won't work currently because it only returns a FixedQueue

    Character copyChar;

    while((copyChar = original.get()) != '0')
        copy.put(copyChar);

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I don`t understand, how i can grab original Queue:(

Comment: Well, now i understand little bit more, you create copy of FixedQueue,ok, then if  i understand right i can create other Queue, but Schildt want that i put content one Queue to other Queue, and use static method.

Comment: I can made it with method what you give me, but when i run , that code state in loop, and dont stop, how you say i can  use if/else, where i`m need put if/else?

Answer (score 0):

Queue interface provides you only several methods, and principal is simple as you know (FIFO - first in first out), and methods (*add, offer, poll, peek*). So you can put only at the end, and get only from head.

Using the Queue interface you can't copy elements of one queue to other without removing elements from source queue.

If you are implementing your own Queue, it should also implement Iterable interface, so that it could provide Iterator from the end of the element to the head. This way you can get iterator, and add each element to the destination queue.

Comment: Hello Ernest, if i understand right, i`m need create my own Queue, and this Queue must implements interface ICharQ

Comment: and then, i can put in this Queue, content other Queue, that seems like answer other man , they described earlier. am i right ?

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, can you write how would it look

Comment: As @GhostCat mentioned, it does not work like this. Little clue:
`
static <T> void copy(MyQueue<T> src, MyQueue<T> dest) {
        Iterator<T> iterator = src.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T element = iterator.next();
            dest.add(element);
        }
    }
`

Comment: And iterator ` @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return new ListNodeIterator<>(head);
        }`

Comment: It does not work like this, i can't do for you all assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to gave solved this issue by adding get and set methods for q, putloc and getloc and implementing them in each class separately, and then implementing static copy() method in ICharQ interface.
Here is a snippet that I added to ICharQ :

```html
 void setQ(char[] q);

    char[] getQ();

    int getPutloc();

    int getGetloc();

    void setPutloc(int p);

    void setGetloc(int g);

    static ICharQ copy(ICharQ a, ICharQ b) {
        b.setQ(a.getQ());
        b.setPutloc(a.getPutloc());
        b.setGetloc(a.getGetloc());
        return b;
    }
```

And here is the implementation in the classes:

```html
public void setQ(char[] q) {
        char[] a = new char[q.length];
        System.arraycopy(q, 0, a, 0, q.length);
        this.q = a;
    }

    public char[] getQ() {
        return q;
    }

    public int getPutloc() {
        return putloc;
    }

    public int getGetloc() {
        return getloc;
    }

    public void setPutloc(int p) {
        putloc = p;
    }

    public void setGetloc(int g) {
        getloc = g;
    }
```

Looks the following way when called from main:

```html
        ICharQ.copy(q1, q2);
```

However, I expect there may be issues when converting to CircularQueue as it requires adding +1 to the array size - unfortunately, have not solved that little problem yet.
P. S. Don't judge strictly, just started learning nearly a month ago, but found this task very interesting, and would love to discuss it more here.